# PHP Socket issue - disconnect immediately after connecting

Tags: php, c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to establish TCP connection between two sockets: PHP socket and wxSocket.
For now I use very simple PHP script: I create socket (socket_create()) and connect (socket_connect()). I examine traffic via Wireshark and via C++ App printouts, and what is the result: connection is established (3-way-handshake), but immediately after connecting, connection is being closed (closing the connection is initialized by PHP server side). That is strange, because I do not use socket_close(). 
Does socket_conect() can handle automatic disconnection?
Does anyone know how to prevent disconnecting?

Regards.

Comment: I think the socket is closed by the other side. Can you provide some code?

Comment: Your PHP script probably finished. When it finishes, all connections are closed. You have to keep it running if you want to prevent that. Show your code otherwise it's only possible to assume something (as tpaksu said).

Comment: How are you invoking the php script? If it's via a webserver, then it's most likely subject to max execution time and whatnot and will shut itself down after a fixed period of time.